# Different margins of the elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can not understand why the mobile version of the elements and INPUT SELECT different spacing and length, everything looks like a crooked.
[image]

And yet, as the mobile version align the red button in the middle?

You can see live code of my site - [here](http://dohms.ru/pillow.php?p_id=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch all of the container's classes with Bootstrap's `text-center` class and it'll work properly (tested).

This:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-6" id="d-btn-order">
    <input type="button" value="Оформить заказ"
           class="btn btn-danger paddbtn"
           name="btn-pillow-order" id="btn-pillow-order">
</div>
```

Is  now this:

```
<div class="text-center" id="d-btn-order">
    <input type="button" value="Оформить заказ"
           class="btn btn-danger paddbtn"
           name="btn-pillow-order" id="btn-pillow-order">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an issue about the Box Model CSS properties http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Some browsers use different references to the margin, padding and internal dimension of the object varying through media types.